# Oracle Instant client in visual studio setup project

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment, instantclient

I have a Visual Studio solution with mixed C# / C++ projects in it.
The created software is using ODBC connection to Oracle DB.

I need to create a new Setup Project inside this solution which will work as single click setup kit.
The easiest I found is using Oracle Instant Client. So I selected the smallest footprint that Oracle needs to be able to add Oracle driver to the ODBC list ([Oracle files list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAexm.png)):

1. oci.dll, ociw32.dll, oraociicus12.dll, oraons.dll, sqora32.dll, sqoras32.dll, sqresus.dll
2. odbc_install.exe, odbc_uninstall.exe

I created a special folder for all above files.
In order to add Oracle driver to ODBC list, I need to run "odbc_install.exe" during the installation, so in "Custom Actions"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ6EI.png).

For some reason, when I run the setup kit on the new brand Windows I don't see the Oracle ODBC driver in the list, so I suppose that setup fails to run "odbc_install.exe", but I don't see why, since I don't know how to check the error code of setup.

Did anyone used Oracle Instant Client in Visual Studio "Setup Project" ?

Any suggestions are very welcome!!!

Comment: Consider to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html, then you have to copy only a single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the way the solution uses the connection to Oracle.
Is there anyone that can help me packaging the "Oracle Instant Client" into VS Setup Kit and auto-run the "odbc_install.exe" afterwords ?

Comment: Yes - that's the usual answer - use Managed Data Access driver.  But that uses Oracle 12 client, and if you have to connect to an Oracle 9 DB it won't work. I have to deploy 11.2.4 client, and seemingly nobody has an answer for that.